# Setting GitHub actions environment input to a default value of empty

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following code snippet in my GitHub workflow:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        required: true
        description: Environment
```

The problem is that developers might choose the environment first and then switch to a different branch. After switching to a different branch, the default behavior from GitHub is to reset the environment value to the default one. This behavior leads to executing the workflow on the wrong environment by mistake by the developers.

I want to set the default value of the environment to empty and make it required to raise an error when someone changes the branch and executes the workflow by mistake. I checked the relevant questions on StackOverflow and the GitHub documentation but couldn't find an answer.

I also tried some workarounds in my workflow but they didn't work:

1. This one didn't work and GitHub ignored the default value as if it didn't exist. I believe it needs the `''` to be an existing environment to show it.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        required: true
        description: Environment
        default: ''
```

2. I also tested the previous solution, but with the input type `choice`, and didn't work for the same reason until I added `''` to the options. But I tested this with `choice` as a PoC, just to check if something similar might work with other input types. But I eventually need it to work with the `environment` input type.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: choice
        required: true
        description: Environment
        options:
        - ''
        - development
        - staging
        - production
        default: ''
```

3. I also tried to add the options to the input type `environment` to check if it would extend the environment values but didn't work. Trying this didn't make sense to me, but worth mentioning.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        required: true
        description: Environment
        options:
        - ''
        default: ''
```

I'm open also to other solutions as well, but notice that we use GitHub Teams and not the Enterprise one.

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried and didn't work.

Comment: With its default behavior, can you not handle this programmatically e.g. in the first step using Bash?

Answer (score 0):

I’m also facing this issue. Further more I want to build two manual workflows: first one only for dev, test environments and the other one only for integration environment and I cannot just choose what environments I want to use because they would all be listed in the dropdown.

The solution would be to use the input type choice like you suggested and instead on relying on Secrets & Variables from the environment, you can rely on the ones from the repository.
The drawback is that if you need to use a secret/variable specific for an environment you would need to name it: dev-secret, test-secret, integration-secret, same for variables.